# What gives Dapper Labs the right to "own" and sell the NBA top shots?

Tags: nft, legal

AFAIK, NFT ownership does not include any legal right.
But in order to sell the ownership in the first place, you do have to "own" it, and that can be done only by a legal agreement, can't it? Did they sign something with the NBA? otherwise, anyone can "sell" NBA moves.